# Testing my GWT application in Internet Explorer 8 I found an issue about CSS resource

Tags: java, css, internet-explorer, gwt

I set images for both enable & disable modes like

```
@Source("com/mysite/image_enable.png")
ImageResource imEnabled();

@Source("com/mysite/image_disable.png")
ImageResource imDisabled();
```

It works perfectly in all browsers(FF, Chrome) except IE 8. Instead of enable-image i get disable in all cases.

I use the following way:

```
ImageResource disabledSrc;
```

later...

```
if (disabledSrc != null && enabledSrc != null) {
            setImage(disabledSrc);
        }
```

where

```
protected void setImage(final ImageResource img) {
        AbstractImagePrototype prototype = AbstractImagePrototype.create(img);
        prototype.applyTo(image);
    }
```

Document mode: IE7 Standards

Would you like to provide me with an advice how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: How are you using the `ImageResource`? (you're talking about CSS in the title). Also, which permutation is IE using? (what's the _document mode_ in the F12 Developer Tools?)

Comment: partially updated about your questions, Thomas

Comment: Is `image` an `Image` widget or an `ImagePrototypeElement`? (if it's an `Image`, why not use `setResource` then?) What's the DOM/CSS of the image after the change? Note: you're using the `ie6` permutation, any reason your page is not in "IE8 Standards", maybe start by fixing that and use the `ie8` permutation; note: `ie6` will be removed soon!)

Comment: I found: the problem was bound to third-party side, where I looked for status parameter to make image disabled or enabled, I fixed the part and now my side works correctly. Any case I really appreciate your help, Thomas. It's resourceful to me, a lot of thanks to you.